ConvertFrom-Json breaks appsettings.json losing settings
We have a release pipeline to deploy some websites.  A part of this requires some minor Powershell to read the appsettings.json. This has worked well for a variety of application over the years.
Moving to Serilog has required minor changes to the appsettings.json that is being broken by this PowerShell script.
This is an extract of the PowerShell to repeat the issue:


$jsonDir = 'C:\Temp\appsettings.json'
$jsonDirTo = 'C:\Temp\appsettings-altered.json'

$json = Get-Content $jsonDir -raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
$json | ConvertTo-Json| set-content $jsonDirTo



Sample appsettings.json


{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "GeneralSettings": {
    "Setting1": "Value1",
    "Setting2": "Value2",
    "Setting3": "Value3"
  },

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Error",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "c:\\temp\\log.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": false,
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp} [{Level:u3}] {MachineName} - {UserName} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "zformatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "LogDatabase",
          "sinkOptionsSection": {
            "tableName": "Logs",
            "schemaName": "dbo",
            "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
            "AutoCreateSqlDatabase": true,
            "batchPostingLimit": 5,
            "batchPeriod": "0.00:00:01"
          },
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "UserName",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": "100",
                "AllowNull": true
              },
              {
                "ColumnName": "MachineName",
                "DataType": "nvarchar",
                "DataLength": "100",
                "AllowNull": true
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "WithMachineName",
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  }

}



Output:


{
    "DetailedErrors":  true,
    "Logging":  {
                    "LogLevel":  {
                                     "Default":  "Information",
                                     "Microsoft.AspNetCore":  "Warning"
                                 }
                },
    "AllowedHosts":  "*",
    "GeneralSettings":  {
                            "Setting1":  "Value1",
                            "Setting2":  "Value2",
                            "Setting3":  "Value3"
                        },
    "Serilog":  {
                    "MinimumLevel":  {
                                         "Default":  "Debug",
                                         "Override":  "@{Microsoft=Error; Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics=Error; Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime=Error}"
                                     },
                    "WriteTo":  [
                                    "@{Name=File; Args=}",
                                    "@{Name=Console}",
                                    "@{Name=MSSqlServer; Args=}",
                                    "@{Name=Async; Args=}"
                                ],
                    "Enrich":  [
                                   "WithMachineName",
                                   "FromLogContext"
                               ]
                }
}



You can see that the first part of the appsettings.json hasn't changed, but the Serilog part has. I believe it is converting them to objects and losing the values assigned to them.
Could someone please advise on why it is doing this and how I can prevent it from losing the values?

Missing -Depth in your ConvertTo-Json call. See linked answer.
